# node.js: confusion with order of callbacks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, nonblocking

I have just started with node.js. I find the asynchronous coding style it uses to be very impressive indeed. However, for those of us who are used to Java and Python it does take some time to get used to it.

I know the following code works fine. This is verified by several questions on this forum. I have also tried it on my own.

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        //throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
        console.log("Server started");
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html); 
        response.write("Other things");
        response.end();  
    }).listen(3000);
});
```

The way I am interpretting this is as follows:

```
1. Try reading the html file
   i. When done create a server 
   ii. Send it over to the client
2. Do everything else.
```

However, we can also have a chain of thoughts as follows:

```
1. Create the server
2. Try reading the file
   i. When done. Send it over to the client
3. In the meanwhile do anything else the server might be asked to do.
```

The code corresponding to the second chain of thoughts is:

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
        console.log("Server started");
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
            if (err) {
            //throw err; 
            }
            response.write(html);
            response.write("Other things");
        });
        response.end();  
}).listen(3000);
```

While the first code works as expected. The second one displays nothing at all in the browser.

Why is the second chain of thoughts wrong?

Comment: You posted the same code twice.  In your code you have a basic error -- you are calling `response.end()` outside of the readFile callback, so you are likely closing the response before you get to where you do the `response.write` calls.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I posted the 'other' code now.

Comment: Joe: You were also write about the callback ordering mistake. If you add that as an answer. I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: One key difference in these approaches (ignoring, for now, the error that @Joe pointed out) is that the callback to `createServer` is called multiple times (once per request) while the callback to `readFile` is called once.  So the second version will read the file on every request; the first will do so once.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what happens here is that the following function gets called each time there is an incoming request:

```
function(request, response) { 
    console.log("Server started");
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write(html); 
    response.write("Other things");
    response.end();  
}
```

You replaced that with:

```
function(request, response) { 
    console.log("Server started");
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
        //throw err; 
        }
        response.write(html);
        response.write("Other things");
    });
    response.end();  
}
```

Now here, it will run the following:

1. Write the header
2. Queue the readFile
3. Immediately execute the following: `response.end();`
4. By the time it is done reading the file and wants to write the contents, you already ended the response